# Why I can't access some pages or directories on my localhost XAMPP?

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, localhost

First of all, I already dug the internet but I couldn't find a solution.

**So, Here's what I did to my website and my step-by-step questions:**

1. I have a project running in my XAMPP

**(Edited localhost to 127.0.0.1:80)**

**(Edited htdocs to my workspace folder)**

2. I tried setting up an `htaccess` file for my website just to remove php and html extensions:

*Here you can see it's content:*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

3. I also have Visual Studio's `Live Server` Plugin which generates random amount of **port**. (Might be interfering?)
4. Sometimes I have access to `index.php` sometimes I don't.
5. I don't have access to `/icons/...` directory all the time.

I really need a serious help right here or I might lose my temper losing my project :(

*My best of appreciations to the solver in advance <3*

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, could you please do mention FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect/rewrite? That will help us to help you, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for responding but I fixed the problem (See the reply I marked as an answer). Much thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That rewriting configuration you posted makes no sense. How should the rewriting engine decide which rule to use? Do you expect it to somehot magically guess ?

Take a look at this instead and work out the difference:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

A better variant would be that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [END]
```

And a general remark: you should always prefer to implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration. Distributed configuration files (".htaccess") come with a number of disadvantages, they should only be used if no other alternative exists (read: if you are using a cheap hosting provider and have no access to the real configuration).

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately I never had the chance or time to learn about http servers' host config. But apparently that's a loss for me and I'm going to dig in it. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. But I would like to point out that you most likely miss understood my last statement. Such rewriting rules as used here can be implemented at various locations, in the server's host configuration files or in distributed configuration files. But they are the same rules (more or less...).